# Ubuntu 17.04 wont install any packages or setups from terminal

Tags: 17.04

hey Dears i cant install any program on my Ubuntu from when i upgrade it to 17.04.
 I am not Sure the problem is from the version or my OS please.. replay

Comment: Please [edit] and post the full error messages.

Comment: You'll have to give us a heck of a lot more information if you'd like a reasonable answer to your problems.

Comment: OK Sorry, I start using Linux a Month ago so i,am not good to it. but when i had Ubuntu 16.04 i install programs from terminal its working but when i upgrade it to 17.04 it does`s  work i cant install programs like brackets , Team viewer  , the errors like : The following packages have unmet dependencies. and the  next line  is :  brackets : Depends: libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0) but it is not installable

Comment: As I said, the problem has been identified by George in your other question. I suggest you follow up on that one.

Comment: OK i delete this question so you can define on my first question